# SQL to Pandas - Aggregation over Partition python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

what is the best way to aggregate values based on a particular over partition by :

SQL :

```
select 
a.*, 
b.vol1 / sum(vol1) over (
  partition by a.sale, a.d_id, 
  a.month, a.p_id
) vol_r, 
a.vol2* b.vol1/ sum(b.vol1) over (
  partition by a.sale, a.d_id, 
  a.month, a.p_id
) vol_t
from 
sales1 a 
left join sales2 b on a.sale = b.sale
and a.d_id = b.d_id 
and a.month = b.month
and a.p_id = b.p_id
```

what would be the equivalent of this to pandas python?

Input :

sales1 :

| sale | d_id | month | p_id | vol2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11.314 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 20.065 |

sales2 :

| sale | d_id | month | p_id | vol1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11.314 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 21 |

output :

| sale | d_id | month | p_id | vol1 | vol2 | vol_r | vol_t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11 | 11 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 11.314 | 11.314 | 1 | 11.314 |
| 2 | 580 | 4 | 9 | 21 | 20.065 | 1 | 20.065 |

Comment: can you ask the question in the proper way, with a sample dataframe, and expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy I have added the sample inputs and output

Comment: kindly provide code that can be copied. you can try : ``df.to_dict('records')`` for both dataframes

Comment: @sammywemmy please take a look thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is the join, similar to the left join in your sql code. One thing I noticed is that four columns are repeated in your code : `'sale', 'd_id', 'month', 'p_id'`, in the joins and windowing. In sql, you can just create a window reference at the end of your code and reuse. In python, you can store it in a variable and reuse (gives a clean look). I also use these values as index, since at some point, there will be a windowing operation (again, the reuse):

```
index = ['sale', 'd_id', 'month', 'p_id']

df1 = df1.set_index(index)

df2 = df2.set_index(index)

merged = df1.join(df2, how='left')
```

Next, groupby on the index and get the aggregate sum for `vol1`. Since we need the aggregate aligned to each row, in pandas the `transform` helps with that:

```
grouped = merged.groupby(index)
partitioned_sum = grouped.vol1.transform('sum')
```

From here, we can create `vol_r` and `vol_t` via the assign method, and drop the `vol1` column:

```
(merged.assign(vol_r = merged.vol1.div(partitioned_sum), 
               vol_t = lambda df: df.vol_r.mul(df.vol2))
       .drop(columns='vol1')
       .reset_index()
)

   sale  d_id  month  p_id    vol2     vol_r     vol_t
0     2   580      4     9  11.000  0.084653  0.931185
1     2   580      4     9  11.000  0.087070  0.957766
2     2   580      4     9  11.000  0.161611  1.777716
3     2   580      4     9  11.314  0.084653  0.957766
4     2   580      4     9  11.314  0.087070  0.985106
5     2   580      4     9  11.314  0.161611  1.828462
6     2   580      4     9  20.065  0.084653  1.698566
7     2   580      4     9  20.065  0.087070  1.747052
8     2   580      4     9  20.065  0.161611  3.242716
```

Comment: here your output differs right, I have 3 rows in my output you have 9.
I understand that when you merge as there are same rows on which we are joining but it doesn't happen when I execute sql

Comment: i ran your sql code before running the pandas code and it returned 9 rows

Comment: can you please also tell me how will I assign this to a new column in dataframe

Comment: you assign a new column with `assign`. The pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#) is your friend.